# Map: How to get all keys associated with a value?

Tags: java, collections

Given a Map, how do I look up all keys associated with a particular value?

For example:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(1, 5);
map.put(2, 2);
map.put(3, 5);
Collection<Integer> keys = map.values(5); // should return {1, 3}
```

I'm looking for something similar to Google Collections' [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) where values are not unique.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With plain `java.util.Map` implementations, I am afraid you must iterate through the map entries and test each value:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getValue().equals(desiredValue) {
    keys.add(entry.getKey());
  }
}
```

If you want better performance, you may want to build up a parallel mapping from values to lists of keys. I don't know of any existing collection doing this, but it should not be difficult to implement.

**From Java 8 onwards you can use map.forEach:**

```
map.forEach((k,val) -> {
      if (val.equals(desiredValue) {
        keys.add(k);
      }
});
```