# Get the map keys and not the map values

Tags: java

I have some data like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> foo
```

Now I can get the corresponding `String` with `foo.get(1)`

But is it also possible to get all the `Integer`s which have the `String` "abc"?

Like this pseudo code: `Integer[] someMore = foo.getKeys("abc")`

Comment: For that you need to create your own implementation to find keys with specific values... :)

Comment: you can loop through the map and check if the value for a certain key == the String you are looking for then add it to a arrayList

Comment: If that is the use case, then you have created the Map incorrectly, you need to swap the key and value.

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005816/map-how-to-get-all-keys-associated-with-a-value ?

Comment: You have to iterate over the map and find all keys with a given value. This is nowhere near as efficient as the opposite though. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/46908/17713

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0564.html might helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Set<Integer> myInts = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : foo.entrySet()) { // go through the entries
    if(entry.getValue().equals("abc")) {             // check the value
        myInts.add(entry.getKey());                  // add the key
    }
}
// myInts now contains all the keys for which the value equals "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map` doesn't provide **look-up by values**. We need to do it by iterating over the `Map` entries

```
Set<Integer> matchingKeys =  new HashSet<Integer>();
for(Entry<Integer, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
    if(e.getValue().equals("abc")) {
          matchingKeys.add(e.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that with a regular map. You would have to call `foo.entrySet()` and create the array on your own.

Maybe you would be interested in using a bidirectional map. Here's a thread where you can read a bit about that.
[Bi-directional Map in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699492/bi-directional-map-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new Map<Integer, String>();
ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals("abc")) {
    arraylist.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```